# Converting javascript arrow function to a normal function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently going through the Angular tutorial and came across the following code:

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes().then( heroes => heroes.find( hero => hero.id === id ));
}
```

Out of curiosity, I decided to rewrite the callback function using a normal function:

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes().then( heroes => heroes.find( this.findHero, id));
}

findHero(hero: Hero, index: number, array: Hero[]): boolean {
    if(hero.id === this.id){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'HeroService'.`

How may I refer to the `id` parameter passed to my callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` (number) property is defined as an argument of the function `getHero`, thus, is not available in your function `findHero`. You tried to use `this.id` but the compiler is telling you that such a property does not exits in your class `HeroService`, which is correct of course, as if you wanted to have that property as part of your service then you would have to do something like this in your `getHero` method.

```
getHero(id: number, ...etc) {
    this.id = id;
    // etc.
}
```

However, that would bring you another problem: as your method `getHeroes` seems to be async code (I can tell because it is returning a `Promise`) this approach will cause you headaches with concurrency problems when your method `getHero` is called twice (or more times) from different parts of the application. The first `getHero` call will set `this.id` to `x` but in the meantime, while the async code is run, another call to `getHero` will set it to `y`, making that the callback `findHero` run in response to the first call use an incorrect value for the `id`(specifically, it will read `y` as the value for `this.id`).

So... long story short. You would probably want to read more about CLOSURES and why they are so important for JavaScript. Short answer to your question, use this:

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes().then( heroes => heroes.find(this.findHero.bind(this, id));
}
```

And define your callback `findHero` as

```
findHero(idToFind: number, hero: Hero, index, array: Hero[]) {
    return hero.id === idToFind;
}
```

The reason why you need this is that the `this` is not passed automatically to the functions that you use as arguments for other functions (or methods, as in this case). So by using `bind` you explicitly BIND the `this` of such a function so that whenever you use `this` in `findHero` it points to the right object. The second argument of `bind` is binding the `id` you are looking for to every call of the function `findHero`, so that whenever the function returned by `bind` is called it happens two things:

1. The `this` is bound to `HeroService`.
2. Along with the arguments the
   function would normally receive, you are also binding another
   argument that will be automatically injected into the arguments of
   calls to that function.

Just one minor note... you are using TypeScript, so the `this` argument in your `bind` is pointless, as TypeScript automatically binds all methods in your class to the current instance, but you need it in this case because you also want to bind the second argument (the `id` to find).

I hope it I helped.

Comment: Hello @damianmr, thank you for your informative comment, it was helpful indeed. I had a look on closures here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures I've learned much from it.

There is just one point I had to change in the code you provided. 
The parameters for the `findHero` function had to be written in this order:

`findHero(idToFind: number, hero: Hero, index: number, array: Hero[]): boolean{`

I am not sure why and so currently googling for an answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Found out why. Arguments for bind are prepended to the bounded function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Thanks,

Comment: @kiseragi I'll update the answer, I wrote it from my memory and thought it was added to the end :)